# Spring Security Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-security, pre-authentication, spring-java-config

I'm trying to use JavaConfig instead of XML configuration for Spring Security.
I would like to use `@PreAuthorization` for declaring access rights.

My Spring Security Config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser( "user" ).password( "password" ).roles( "USER" );
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Once I deploy my web application I receive an error `Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource`.

After some research I found out that I have to add the `aopalliance` library to my project. Unfortunately that didn't resolved my problem.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1558)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:567)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.lazyBean(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:352)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$890899ea.CGLIB$methodSecurityInterceptor$2(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$890899ea$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fba343c4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:326)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$890899ea.methodSecurityInterceptor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace you get.

Comment: Here we go.. https://gist.github.com/mhmpl/8020820

Comment: Please add it to your question. Just the stacktrace not a link please. Also which Spring Security version are you using? The current version doesn't have the method you override.

Answer (score 9):

According to your stacktrace, there’s no `AuthenticationManager` bean in your context.

```
Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
```

It seems that you need to explicitly expose `AuthenticationManager` as a bean; try this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser( "user" ).password( "password" ).roles( "USER" );
    }

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exposing the `AuthenticationManager` as a `@Bean` works to resolve the error in question. But for me it caused other errors, probably because this effectively short-circuits the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

Comment: Nope, it doesn’t short-circuit `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. Take a look at implementation of the [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.0.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java) class.

Comment: Ok, maybe an unfortunate choice of words. It seems that this workaround does short-circuit the *full configuration* of the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.
Just to be clear: I'm still having that issue in my application and every workaround I tried resulted in other errors. For me, it seems that `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` only works for applications with pretty simple security configurations.

Comment: The error I get after this change is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@... to already built object` caused by a call to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder#userDetailsService()`.

Comment: As of Spring Security 3.2, `registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` is now `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` as noted in this [Spring Security blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/spring-security-3-2-0-rc2-released)

Answer (score 5):

from the stacktrace, you don't have authentication manager defiend correctly :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
```

Here is working example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Just add the global method annotation, and change to method to not override and be autowired.

Answer (score 1):

As NimChimpsky notes, Spring 3.2.0.RELEASE requires a configuration update.

Using this configuration, I was getting exactly the same exception as the OP, but only about half the time. The other half of the time the app started up just fine. I assume that there's some kind of race condition.

Originally I was pulling the security configuration in using `@Import` on my root configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
... other annotations ...
public class RootConfig {
   ...
}
```

When I replaced that with

```
public class WebAppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }
}
```

the problem went away. Didn't dive into the reasons why, so I can't speak to that, but you might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a line `super.configure(auth);` in the overriding method `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`.

After it was removed, the exception is gone.