# Spring Security 3.2 code based configuration. Form login + global method security

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm upgrading Spring security from 3.1 to 3.2 in my project. Since 3.2 supports code based configurations I have decided to convert old XML based configuration to Java code.

I receive the exception said that no bean with name `"authenticationManager"` has been found every time I try to start an application. This exception start appearing after `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation been added to the configuration class.

**Spring framework version**: 4.0.0.RELEASE

**Spring security version**: 3.2.0.RELEASE

Old Xml config looks like that:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                        jsr250-annotations="enabled"
                        pre-post-annotations="enabled"
                        proxy-target-class="true"/>

  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/home" 
                authentication-failure-url = "/login?login_error=1" />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index" />
  </http>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authUserDetailService">
      <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

New Java config class looks like that:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                List<GrantedAuthority> list = new ArrayList<>();
                String login = null;
                String password = null;

                logger.debug("Started loading user by name: " + username);
                if (username.equals("admin")) {
                    login = "admin";
                    password = "admin";
                    list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                    list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
                }

                if (username.equals("user")) {
                    login = "user";
                    password = "user";
                    list.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                logger.debug("User " + username + ": " + login + ", " + password);

                return new User(login, password, true, true, true, true, list);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index");
    }
}
```

Text of exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppFrontController' defined in file [/mnt/data/Docs/IdeaProjects/test/target/test/WEB-INF/classes/sample/web/controllers/WebAppFrontController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:224)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.getAdvice(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$ProxyCallbackFilter.hashCode(CglibAopProxy.java:916)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer$EnhancerKey$$KeyFactoryByCGLIB$$4ce19e8f.hashCode(<generated>)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:366)
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:466)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:421)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:199)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.lazyBean(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:377)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:262)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8215642a.CGLIB$methodSecurityInterceptor$10(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8215642a$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8ae0c10a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8215642a.methodSecurityInterceptor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 80 more
```

I've been looking at this for a two days now but can't find a solution for this issue.

**UPDATE**

Root config:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "sample.service")
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, MvcConfiguration.class, RepositoryConfig.class})
public class RootConfig {
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("db.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

Web application Initializer:

```java
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);

        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic sessionInView = servletContext.addFilter("sessionInView", new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        sessionInView.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code which loads this configuration.

Comment: You get the stacktrace, but is it at debug level? Does everything else work? I ask because this same configuration works fine for me.

Comment: Tip on your `RootConfig` instead of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ` add a `@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties)` to the class. For the `WebAppInitializer` I would suggest to extend the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

Comment: @RobWinch No. it is an error. 

*ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed*

Comment: Just in case this is important: before I placed *@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity* annotation to configuration everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you start your application context if you only use the SecurityConfig and nothing else? It works just fine for me. I see you have a RepsitoryConfig. Are you using Spring Data within Spring Security somewhere? If so, perhaps this is causing issues w/ ordering.

Comment: I have created empty project. There are only two contexts now: MVC and Security. I checked out, everything works fine after MVC context deleted from Root context though application become quite useless :-) If both MVC and Security contexts are enabled and Security context have enabled both WebSecurity and GlobalMethodSecurity then error occur again. 

I have also created a repository on github with this example project just to show the whole picture. It is available on https://github.com/io-german/spring-security-code-config-example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security Java Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651043/spring-security-java-config)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stack trace already contains all information needed to find solution. There is no AuthenticationManager bean in Spring context. So it need to be defined explicitly.

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class contains authenticationManagerBean() method. Its JavaDoc says:

> Override this method to expose the AuthenticationManager from
> configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) to be exposed as a
> Bean. For example:
>
> ```
>  @Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager") 
>  @Override 
>  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {  
>     return super.authenticationManagerBean(); 
>  }
> ```

Another thing (I don't actually understand why this is so) is that you need to configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder using configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) method defined in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and not with configureGlobal() method.

So the last version of my SecurityConfig is that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index");
    }
}
```